# JQuery Validate Dynamic Table

Tags: jquery, html, validation, jquery-validate, dynamic-tables

I'm using the JQuery validation plug to validate my entire form. I also have a dynamic table on my registration page where the user can register more people. I can validate the rest of the form fine but my goal is to validate the table inputs just the same. Here is my jfiddle code: [tables](http://jsfiddle.net/T3MgX/)

I don't know why the add line won't work there but it definitely works on my page. Anyway, that code ends up validate ONLY the first row of my table, but I want it to validate every single row. Can anyone see any problems with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The end brakets are missing, just add `});` at the end. check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/T3MgX/1/)

Comment: Yah for some reason the validation stuff for the table works in fiddle but not on the webpage. I have no idea why, can you see anything else wrong with it?